Apport on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS getting permission errors for ProcEnvironment and ProcMaps
I've been given a number of crash dumps from Apport running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I don't have access to the server in question, but I have access to the Test version, which I'm told should be configured the same.
The problem is that the crash dumps contain the following lines:
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Sun Dec  1 14:56:00 2024
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
ExecutableTimestamp: 1629467367
ProcCmdline: Some\ uWSGI\ worker\ 1
ProcEnviron: Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'environ'
ProcMaps: Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'maps'
ProcStatus:
...

It does contain the core file, which I can unpack and get loaded into GDB, but the problem is that without the ProcMaps I don't believe I can even know which libraries would have been loaded into which areas of memory.
I've seen plenty of examples online where ProcEnviron and ProcMaps have the same issue, but nothing that seems to indicate why it would fail to be collected.
As far as I can tell, the configuration seems fairly default, with Apport collection turned on. I don't see anything Apport related in the kernel logs indicating an AVC denial for /proc//environ or /proc//maps   (I see them for other things, but not for apport)

Ubuntu 18.04 went EOL in 2023. Update to a supported release and see if the problems persist.
